# Limit the amount of items in a OneToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am using the Play! Framework and am wondering if there is an easy way to limit the amount of items in a OneToMany relationship can be limited. (The Play! Framework uses Hibernate)

I have a Model where only 5 children are allowed to be added to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use the `@Size(max=x)` annotation. I know it supports Arrays and Collections, so it should suit what you're looking for.